# mod_rewrite not forwarding encoded hash?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a small collection of text files on a server. The URLs look like this:
http://mysite.com/My%20Text%20File.txt

I have a small PHP script that takes the text file URI as a parameter and converts the text file to JSON:
http://mysite.com/json.php?file=/My%20Text%20File.txt

And I have a rewrite rule that makes it pretty:
RewriteRule ^(.*).json$ /json.php?file=$1.txt

And it works great. Now the URI for the JSON is identical to the text URIs, except for the file extension. But if I have a text file with an encoded has in the name:
http://mysite.com/Text%20File%20%231.txt

Apache has no trouble opening the text file. Similarly the "real" URI works:
http://mysite.com/json.php?file=/Text%20File%20%231.txt

But the rewrite rule flubs it. So the "file" GET parameter that PHP sees is "/Text%20File%20" -- with the hash and after missing.

I could avoid files with hashes in the name, but I'm curious why the hash gets unencoded when other encoded characters do not, and I can't find any reference to this elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`B` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).json$ /json.php?file=$1.txt [B]
```

Comment: I always wondered what that flag did. Perfect. Thanks so much.